# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_120 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (96, 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

У меня есть такой код:

```
a=[[1,23,345,235,235,644,757],
[2,455,325,235578,23524,6413,757567],
[3,123,125,2375,23554,64123,75778],
[...],
[35,244,245,231235,2158935,6567944,7567557]]

b=[[1],[-1],[0],[...],[1]]

c=np.array(a)
d=np.array(b)
print(c.shape)
print(d.shape)

inputs = Input(shape=(96,7))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(c, d)
```

Выводит:

```
(96, 7)
(96, 1)
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_120 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (96, 7)
```

Никак не могу понять в чем же тут проблема. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

у вас тут похоже две проблемы:

1. число строк (образцов) в размерности модели не учитывается. Т.е. вместо `inputs = Input(shape=(96,7))` используйте: `inputs = Input(shape=(7,))`
2. На последнем слое вы использовали 10 выходных нейронов (иными словами вы хотите посчитать вероятности принадлежности к 10-ти классам), а на вход (в качестве `y`/`target`) вы подаете тензор/матрицу с одним столбцом (модель же ожидает 10 столбцов).

Для того чтобы исправить 2-ю проблему можно категоризировать (One-Hot-Encoding) `d`, получив в итоге "`One Hot Encoded`" матрицу с 10-ю столбцами.

```
Пример:

In [46]: from keras.utils import to_categorical

In [47]: Y = to_categorical(d, num_classes=10)

In [48]: Y
Out[48]:
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

---

Весь исправленный код:

```
from keras import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.utils import to_categorical

a=[[1,23,345,235,235,644,757],
[2,455,325,235578,23524,6413,757567],
[3,123,125,2375,23554,64123,75778],
[35,244,245,231235,2158935,6567944,7567557]]

b=[[1],[-1],[0],[1]]

X = np.array(a)
Y = to_categorical(np.array(b), num_classes=10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=7))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(X, Y)
```